# Are these functions Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ using this theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

The question asks to whether the theorem "bounded function $f$ on $[a,b]$ that is continuous on $(a,b]$ is Riemann integrable" to explain whether these functions are Riemann integrable:

a) $\sin^2(\frac 1x)$

b) $\frac 1x\cdot\sin(\frac 1x)$

c) $\ln x$

I think the answer is Yes, No, No. For the first one, the function is clearly bounded and continuous on $(0,1)$. For the second one, I'm not entirely sure because the function is continuous on $(0,1]$ but is it bounded? The last one the function is unbounded.

Could someone confirm and explain to me more clearly? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

$\frac{1}{x} \sin(1/x)$ is not bounded: consider the sequence of points $x_n=\frac{1}{\pi/2+2n\pi}$ and notice $\sin(1/x_n)=1$.

Also, in all of these you should be a bit careful: you need to give some alternate definition of them at $x=0$ in order for the question of Riemann integrability to make sense. As your theorem shows, the *choice* of this value is of no consequence, but still, the concept of proper Riemann integrability is restricted to functions whose domain is a closed bounded interval.

Comment: oh I see! Thanks so much!